# What happens under the hood when bytes converted to String in Java?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8, byte

I have a problem when trying to convert bytes to String in Java, with code like:

```
byte[] bytes = {1, 2, -3};

byte[] transferred = new String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
```

and the original bytes are not the same as the transferred bytes, which are respectively

```
[1, 2, -3]
[1, 2, -17, -65, -67]
```

I once thought it is due to the UTF-8 charset mapping for the negative "-3". So I change it to "-32". But the transferred array remains the same!

```
[1, 2, -32]
[1, 2, -17, -65, -67]
```

So I strongly want to know exactly what happens when I call new String(bytes) :)

Comment: Where did you come up with 1, 2, -3? Is that even valid UTF-8?

Comment: Keep in mind, you're looking at the numeric representation of the bytes according to Java, in which everything is signed. The value printed as -3 is actually the 8-bit value 0xFD or 0b11111101.

Comment: Since the byte 0xFD corresponds with the first byte of a smattering of Arabic Presentation Forms-A code points, it might be expanding one of those into a proper UTF-8 sequence. Most of the Arabic Presentation Forms resolve to 3 bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: @Necreaux the 1, 2, -3 is an example. The real bytes come from the binary bytes of a thrift object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all sequences of bytes are valid in UTF-8.

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a smart scheme with a variable number of bytes per code point, the form of every byte indicating how many other bytes follow for the same code point.

Refer to [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description):

[image: table]

Now let's see how it applies to your `{1, 2, -3}`:

Bytes `1` (hex `0x01`, binary `00000001`) and `2` (hex `0x02`, binary `00000010`) stand alone, no problem.

Byte `-3` (hex `0xFD`, binary `11111101`) is the start byte of a 6-byte sequence (which is actually illegal in the [current UTF-8 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629)), but your byte array does not have such a sequence.

Your UTF-8 is invalid.  The Java UTF-8 decoder replaces this invalid byte `-3` with Unicode codepoint [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) (also see [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm)).  in UTF-8, codepoint U+FFFD is hex `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD` (binary `11101111 10111111 10111101`), represented in Java as `-17, -65, -67`.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, `byte` is signed, where negative values are above 127. And those you used (-3 = 0xFD, -32 = 0xE0) are not valid in UTF-8, so they both are converted to Unicode codepoint `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which is converted back to UTF-8 as 0xEF = -17, 0xBF = -65, 0xBD = -67.

You cannot expect that random byte values are correctly interpreted as UTF-8 text.

Comment: That is right that I cannot expect any bytes are correct UTF-8 :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a line in the documentation of the constructor:

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

This is definitely the culprit here, as `-3` is invalid in UTF-8. By the way, if you are really interested, you can always download the source of the `rt.jar`, and debug into it.

Answer (score 1):

The encoded values you are getting, [-17, -65, -67] correspond to Unicode code point `0xFFFD`. If you look up that code point, [the Unicode specification](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf) tells you that `0XFFFD` "used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode." And as others have pointed out, `-3` without any followup code-units is broken UTF-8, so this character is appropriate.

Comment: "followup characters" should be "followup code-units" or "continuation bytes"